# Facing error 2349 while calling stripe to accept payment

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, strapi, cloudinary, stripes

[here is my code and the error i am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCs4b.png)

here is the installed dependiencies : dependencies": {
"@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.12.7",
"@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.12.7",
"@strapi/provider-upload-cloudinary": "^4.13.1",
"@strapi/strapi": "4.12.7",
"better-sqlite3": "8.5.0",
"express": "^4.18.2",
"stripe": "^13.6.0"
},

I tried to delete the nodemodules  and packagelock.json and reinstalled it but does'nt worked
deleted stripe and re installed it many times still facing same issue

error :This expression is not callable.
Type 'typeof import("stripe")' has no call signatures. ts 2349
I'm using Vite+React

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 1):

To import `stripe` module in TypeScript, Stripe should be imported as a default import as [explained](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#usage-with-typescript) here. For example,

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = new Stripe('sk_test_...', {
  apiVersion: '2023-08-16',
});
```